# How do I know if an NPC is hostile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I see an NPC from a distance I'm uncertain of whether or not they will attack me on sight. What I've done up until now is save the game, go up to them, and if they're hostile I'll re-load my save and kill them using a bow.

Is there anyway to know if an NPC is hostile from a distance?

Comment: I wish. I do the same as you.

Comment: If only it were more like real life!

Comment: @fluffy - I think I would prefer real life be more like the game :)

Comment: I've wondered that as well. However so far (at level 32) 99% of encounters in the wild are with bandits, mages and otherwise animals that are *very* protective of their territory. Hunters typically live alone with a single tent and a campfire. Stormcloak camps... well this reminds me... if you sneak close enough you'll often hear a conversation which quickly hints you if you're dealing with bandits and other criminals. :)

Comment: quicksave and fire away! If you get bounty, then quick load.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Shoot an arrow near the target while sneaking.  If they are hostile to you, they'll start searching for you and you can see your stealth eye open a little bit.  If they are not hostile, then they'll ignore your shot.

Courtesy of agent86:

[image: A funny comic. Ha ha ha.]

Comment: Illusion spells near the target also generate sound on impact and would serve this purpose without consuming an arrow (best if you also have the silent casting perk to prevent sound at your location).

Comment: @David B good point, but keep in mind you can pick up the arrow anyway after killing the hostile target.  The throw voice shout works just as well here.

Comment: Yes, throw voice is good too.  It does not require the silent casting perk.

Comment: That errant arrow [must've been his imagination](http://memebase.com/2011/12/13/internet-memes-he-must-have-an-active-imagination/)

Comment: You can just shoot them directly with the arrow. If it's an important friendly NPC they won't die and since you are sneaking they won't know it was you who attacked them. I've had multiple conversations with smiling NPC's with an arrowhead protruding from their eyeball.

Comment: @dpatchery well it does matter when you do 300+ damage with a arrow sneak attack.  Most NPCs will be dead :P

Comment: too bad the arrow wasn't in the knee

Comment: @spartacus You might want to [edit] out the image macro as per: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/ , similar to the [edit to this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/36308/7) in another question mentioned in that blog post.

Comment: @dpatchery: There is at least [one small sidequest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Scroll_For_Anska) with a non-essential NPC just waiting around at the entrance to a dungeon.  She can be one-hit killed at higher levels, which naturally locks you out of the quest.

Comment: @z I don't thin that is a good image try to add something like the compass at the top of the game screen with a red dot that's a sign of hostile enemies as I answered below.

Answer (score 48):

The Detect Life spell conveniently color codes the creatures it detects.
Red creatures are hostile, while creatures which appear blue will not attack you.

In my game, it has saved the life of the maid in Fort Greymoor.
Also, it works through walls :)

The spell is available from merchants (at least in the College of Winterhold) once your Alteration skill is at least 50.

I think I read somewhere that there is an equivalent dragon shout, but I do not know what it is or if it also has the color-coding of Detect Life.

Comment: The Aura Whisper is the name of the shout, it color enemies red, although I don't know if the color is different for allies.

Comment: Aura whisper definitely doesn't.  But then it makes sense, everything that moves is deemed as food to a dragon, after all ;)

Comment: No, I've definitely had bandits appear blue (using detect life) before they alert to me.  Walked right up to them and got jumped.  Also the trigger for putting NPCs in the game is closer than Detect Life's range so sometimes an "empty" hut will not be empty if you get closer.

Comment: @Ben Jacson were the blue bandits technically hostile at a distance? Sometimes they have a 'gaurd' AI where they only turn hostile if you get within a certain range.

Comment: The maid isn't so peaceful when she's been singed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

### Try the PC console command `getav`.

In the game, press the backtick key (`) to open the console.

Target an NPC with your mouse, then type this in the console:

`getav aggression`

It will return a value of 0-2, with 2 being hostile.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the compass at the top of the screen. If you see a red dot, there is a hostile NPC. The red dot will only appear if the hostile NPC or creature detects you. Try to see if you're detected by looking a at the crosseye at the center to the screen. It will appear when you're sneaking. if the eye is wide, your detected. if it's slightly, It's searching for you. If the eye is shut, you're undetedcted.